# Loading an image but onload/onerror not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dom, onerror

I have a div

```html
<div id='cards'>
```

Which I want to fill with images based on some logic. But only when images are first loaded into memory. Otherwise, through `onerror` I wanna fill in some text..

```js
function pasteCard(card, to){
    if (typeof(card) == 'string')
        card = [card];
    var image = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        image[i] = new Image();
        image[i].src = '/sprites/open/' + card[i] + '.png';
        image[i].onload = function() {
            pasteImage(to, image[i]);
        }
        image[i].onerror = function() {            
            pasteText(to, card[i]);
            
        }
        // alert(card[i]) #1
    }

    function pasteImage(to, image) {
        to.append(image);
    }

    function pasteText(to, text) {
        // alert(card[i]) #2
        to.append(text);
    }    
}

pasteCard(['ABC123', 'DEF456', 'GHI789'], $('#cards'));
```

[But this isn't working.](http://jsfiddle.net/7CfEu/)

**Problem/weirdness**: [If only `#2` alert is active it returns nothing.](http://jsfiddle.net/7CfEu/2/) But strangely [if `#1` alert is also active it does kinda work](http://jsfiddle.net/7CfEu/2/)... (but still doesn't load my images, and mostly fails too when other code is involved)

**Question**: Why is it not working without `#1` alert (at least in that jsfiddle)

**suggestions?**: what should I do?

Comment: Your answer is in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1451043/1169519).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onload and onerror events are fired (executed) outside the scope of your function so your variables will be undefined. In the event method you have access to `this` which is the image object. You can set a data attribute to each image and access that in your error event.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7CfEu/4/

Comment: executed or whatever you want to call it, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The callbacks are not in the same scope as your `image` array is - therefor you need to declare a variable then will "connect the scopes" and use it inside the callbacks

also the `i` variable probably changes until the callback is fired - so by using it inside the callback you will get undefined behavior

```
for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        var current_card = card[i];
        var current_image = new Image();
        current_image.onload = function() {
            pasteImage(to, current_image);
        }
        current_image.onerror = function() {
            pasteText(to, current_card);
        }
        current_image.src = '/sprites/open/' + current_card + '.png';
        image[i] = current_image;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7CfEu/6/

(Also - closing the `div` tag is never a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ends up here for same reason I did.

Was going crazy because onload and onerror were not firing in the page I was building.  Tried copy pasting

```
var myimage = new Image();
myimage.onload = function() { alert("Success"); };
myimage.onerror = function() { alert("Fail"); };
myimage.src = "mog.gif" //Doesn't exist.
```

Which was working within codepen and random otherwise blank pages.

Turns out the problem I was having was that I was doing AJAX requests earlier in the page.  This involved authorization which in turn involved a call to

```
setRequestHeader();
```

This was resulting in a *net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND* error instead of the expected *GET mog.gif 404 (Not Found)*

This seemed to prevent proper triggering of events.

Revert with

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "");
```